# set query into response bot microsoft framework

Tags: sql, node.js, botframework

Team I'm trying to set the answer query in an answer into bot microsoft framework

This is what I do:

```
 request = new Request(
      "Here the string that returns me a number for example 763",
         function(err, rowCount, rows) 
            {
                console.log(rowCount + ' row(s) returned');
                process.exit();
            }
        );

 request.on('row', function(columns) {
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
           **session.send(column.value);
             next();**       
     });
         });
 connection.execSql(request);
```

The consult is ok, but I get the error :

> cannot create property 'type' on number

For me Session.send is the way to send a message to the user from bot framewok emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Error - in Sql query syntax erorr:

```
"SELECT Medicina.Nombre FROM Medicina where='Aspirina'"
```

Change column name below query:

```
"SELECT Medicina.Nombre FROM Medicina where column_name='Aspirina'"
```

Comment: Hi jain, shure it is,but is not the problem when I run the proyect I'm having a value from the string...but this value is a number

Comment: Which database have you used?

Comment: SQL Server... but I don't know how can I display y the data into the bot framework... because column.value. I put the data into a string variable but I get other erros.

Comment: Please, try with below query for convert numeric to string:
"SELECT convert(varchar(20),Medicina.Nombre) as  Medicina.Nombre FROM Medicina where column_name='Aspirina'"